# laravel load scope after model created

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have this type of scope inside `RoadOffer` model:

```
public function scopeOfOfferRelationships($query){
    return $query->with(["priceNegotiations", "driver.user", "roadTransport", "serviceProvider", "serviceProvider.company"]);
}
```

then somewhere inside my code I have code like that:

```
$offer = Offer::where('id', $request->offer_id)->first();
$offer->status = 1;
$offer->save();
return $offer->query()->OfOfferRelationships()->where('id', $request->offer_id)->first();
```

I have to write `$offer->query()->OfOfferRelationships()->where('id', $request->offer_id)->first();` in order to load relationships from scope. is there any better way than using `query()`?
If I used `load()` function I could load these relationships but I want to have this `scopeOfOfferRelationships` is this the only way?

Comment: Why don't you use your scope when retrieving the offer in the first place? `Offer::OfOfferRelationships()->where('id', $request->offer_id)->first();`

Comment: Do you need these on every query request? If so you can add them to the $with variable in your model. That way you will always get those relationships loaded without a scope. Loading relations by scope is not really a great practice to get into.

Comment: what if I am changing something inside  `"priceNegotiations", "driver.user", "roadTransport", "serviceProvider", "serviceProvider.company"`  ?  retrieving scope in the first place will not work then.

Comment: What do you mean? Changing some of the array items or changing something on one of the listed models? In any case, you can then simply store the required relations in an array and load/query it whenever needed. I seem to not get the question after all.

Answer (score 0):

**Load relations whenever new record created**

I think observers best approach to achieve this.

First create a an observer Offer model.

```
php artisan make:observer OfferObserver
```

Then register OfferObserver in `AppServiceProvider`

```
Offer::observe(OfferObserver::class)
```

In the `created()` method load offer relations. This method will fire when you created new record. Also if you want to load relations after updating model, copy and paste below code into the `updated()` method

```
 /**
 * Handle the offer "created" event.
 *
 * @param Offer $offer
 * @return void
 */
public function created(Offer $offer)
{
    $offer->load([
       "priceNegotiations", 
       "driver.user", 
       "roadTransport", 
       "serviceProvider", 
       "serviceProvider.company"
    ]);

}
```

**load relations only when you need**

in Offer Model create method for loading relations.

```
public function loadRelations()
{
   $this->load([
       "priceNegotiations", 
       "driver.user", 
       "roadTransport", 
       "serviceProvider", 
       "serviceProvider.company"
   ]);
}
```

Then load relations with `loadRelations()` method when ever you need

```
// update process
$offer->save();
$offer->loadRelations()
return $offer;
```

Comment: If I do that, then what if sometimes I don't want offer to have all these relationships with it? I have `->OfOfferRelationships()` because I want offer to sometimes have these relationships and sometimes don't.